# scikit-learn: Dynamic Inheritance from Estimators for Target Scaling

Tags: python, inheritance, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to achieve the following:
Given an arbitrary sklearn estimator, I want to have a wrapping functionality 
which:

- scales the passed targets before fitting
- internally stores the
  scaling factors
- upon prediction scales predicted targets back to
  the original scale by using

the saved scaling factors.

I have therefor created the following structure:

```
class ZScaler(Scaler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__mean = None
        self.__std = None

    def fit(self, vector, **kwargs):
        self.__mean = np.mean(vector)
        self.__std = np.std(vector)

        return self

    def transform(self, vector):
        return (vector - self.__mean) / self.__std

    def fit_transform(self, vector, **kwargs):
        self.fit(vector)

        return self.transform(vector)

    def inverse_transform(self, vector):
        return (vector * self.__std) + self.__mean
```

Which is used in the following class factory:

```
def TargetScalingEstimatorDecorator(EstimatorClass, ScalerInstance):
    class TargetScalingEstimator(EstimatorClass):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(TargetScalingEstimator, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            self.scaler = deepcopy(ScalerInstance)

        def fit(self, x, y, **fit_params):
            self.scaler.fit(y)
            scaled_y = self.scaler.transform(y)

            super(TargetScalingEstimator, self).fit(x, scaled_y, **fit_params)

            return self

        def predict(self, x):
            scaled_y_hat = super(TargetScalingEstimator, self).predict(x)

            y_hat = self.scaler.inverse_transform(scaled_y_hat)

            return y_hat

    return TargetScalingEstimator
```

Now I can do things like:

```
scaler = ZScaler()
model = sklearn.linear_model.Ridge
params = {'alpha':0.1}
decorated_model = TargetScalingEstimatorDecorator(model, scaler)(**params)
```

So far, so good, that all works well, until I tried using feature_selection.SelectFromModel or any other methods which rely on sklearn.base.clone.
clone looks at the estimators init keywords to determine the parameters to copy over. 
My structure overwrites **init** and calls super with **kwargs, thus resulting in an empty dictionary of parameters.

Has anyone encountered sth like this before, or an idea how to dynamically decorate arbitrary estimators?

Comment: Have a look at the [Pipeline class](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) of scikit-learn. You want something like that.

Comment: @VivekKumar I am already wrapping this in a pipeline. The issue is that the target scaling needs to remember the mean and std of the training target vector and then inversely transform predictions based on these. This seems to not be applicable in a pipeline.

Comment: I was saying that you should look at source code of pipeline and try implementing it yourself. You need the last part of the pipeline to be an inverser transformer to get back original data.